# Simple update not working using positional $ operator

Tags: mongodb

I'm just starting out with Mongo, and following the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/), I can't seem to update a value in a nested array when I apply the same technique.

This is my document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d2cf8ee2b075667d4f0545"),
    "address" : {
        "building" : "522",
        "coord" : [
            -73.95171,
            40.767461
        ],
        "street" : "East   74 Street",
        "zipcode" : "10021"
    },
    "borough" : "Manhattan",
    "cuisine" : "American ",
    "grades" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2014-09-02T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 12
        },
        {
            "grade" : "B",
            "score" : 16,
            "date" : ISODate("2013-12-19T00:00:00Z")
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2013-05-28T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 9
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2012-12-07T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 13
        },
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2012-03-29T00:00:00Z"),
            "grade" : "A",
            "score" : 11
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Glorious Food",
    "restaurant_id" : "40361521"
}
```

and this is my query:

```
db.restaurants.update(
  {
    _id: 'ObjectId("56d2cf8ee2b075667d4f0545")',
    'grades.date': 'ISODate("2014-09-02T00:00:00Z")'
  },
  {
    $set: { 'grades.$.score': 1 }
  }
)
```

I'm sure I must have missed something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove quotes from objectId and date field - please see below:

```
db.restaurants.update(
  {
    _id: ObjectId("56d2cf8ee2b075667d4f0545"),
    "grades.date": ISODate("2014-09-02T00:00:00Z")
  },
  {
    $set: { 'grades.$.score': 1 }
  }
)
```

Comment: Doh. Thanks very much :)